# JWT token not verifying only on first entry

Tags: node.js, api, express, jwt

I have a backend API for handling users with JWT and passsport, using Node.js and Express. The frontend is on Vue and everything works alright, except when a new User signs in, the backend authenticator seems to get a jwt_payload that has an id (which is supposed to be the user's id) that doesn't correspond to anybody. Upon refreshing the page, suddenly the jwt_payload has the correct Id and can find a user. The following is the code for the authenticator and JWT strategy:

JWTStrategy:

```
module.exports = passport => {
        passport.use(
            new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
                User.findById(jwt_payload.id)
               .then(user => {
                    if(user) return done(null, user);
                    return done(null,false);
                })
                .catch(err =>{
                    return done(err, false, {message:"Hubo un error en el servidor"});
                });
            })
        );
    };
```

Authenticator:

```
module.exports = (req,res,next) => {
        passport.authenticate("jwt", function(err,user,info){
            if(err) return next(err);
            if(!user) return res.status(401).json({message:"Acceso denegado - No token"});

            req.user = user;

            next();
        })(req,res,next);
};
```

I followed a guide on how to set up jwt authentication and authorization, users can sign in an register as normal. If it is useful, the Vue frontend checks for a jwt token in localStorage as a second barrier for authorization to the home page, upon openning the home page (which has data that depends on the current user), I get that 401 from the authenticator. I am using vue router to push the home page when the user logs in (logging in saves the jwt token to the localStorage).

Comment: Are you missing the function keyword on `passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done)`

Comment: I don't think that's it. I am using the arrow function notation which essentially does the same thing